# Bash search prompt overlapping value

Tags: bash, prompt

Running a docker alpine container, my PS1 is:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

So when logging into the container, you get

```
root@worker:/$
```

So if I type in something like

```
root@worker:/$ cd /tmp/dir/path
```

And then do a reverse-i-search for `tmp/di`

The prompt looks like this for each character along the way:

```
(reverse-i-search)`t': cd /tmp/dir/path
(reverse-i-search)`tm: cd /tmp/dir/path
(reverse-i-search)`tmp cd /tmp/dir/path
(reverse-i-search)`tmp/cd /tmp/dir/path
(reverse-i-search)`tmp/dd /tmp/dir/path
(reverse-i-search)`tmp/di /tmp/dir/path
```

So now that I've typed `tmp/di`, if I hit the `end` key the prompt looks like this:

```
root@worker:/$tmp/dir/path
```

Worth noting that if I hit `enter` it performs the correct command, and if I scroll back through the history, it shows the correct command, so it's clearly just something to do with the presentation.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with my PS1 or if I've done something else wrong.

Thank you!

**Edit**:

Here is the entire .bashrc

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
alias app='cd /var/www/pricing'

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
shopt -s checkwinsize

case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Comment: What terminal program are you using?  What does `echo $TERM` say?

Comment: This is not a problem with your `PS1` as written above; it will not cause this behavior unless you are adding in non-printing characters such as coloration or effects.

Comment: The $TERM is `xterm-color`. I've also edited the post to include the full .bashrc. I'm using cmder on windows, but the problem also arises when using a normal windows command prompt.